# Importing FlatMap instance breaks Applicative builder syntax

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-cats

For my examples I will be using `Option`s but in my actual code I was using a custom datatype.  Adding the import `import cats.std.option._` will resolve the issue in the examples. I had some code that looked like this:

```
import cats.{FlatMap, Eval, Applicative}
import cats.data.Kleisli
import cats.syntax.all._

implicit val optionApplicative = new Applicative[Option] {
  override def pure[A](x: A): Option[A] = Option(x)
  override def ap[A, B](fa: Option[A])(f: Option[(A) => B]): Option[B] = for {
    a <- fa
    fUnwrapped <- f
  } yield fUnwrapped(a)
}

val test : Option[(Int, String)] = (Option(4) |@| Option("name")).map((_, _))
```

This code was compiling and running just fine.

Next I used `Kleisli` to compose some functions that return `Option`:

```
val test2 : List[Int] => Option[Int] = {
  val f = (xs : List[Int]) => xs.headOption
  val g = (x : Int) => Option(x)
  Kleisli(f).andThen(g).run
}
```

The code did not compile because my data type did not have a `FlatMap` instance. I created one:

```
implicit val optionFlatmap = new FlatMap[Option] {
  override def flatMap[A, B](fa: Option[A])(f: (A) => Option[B]): Option[B] = fa.flatMap(f)
  override def map[A, B](fa: Option[A])(f: (A) => B): Option[B] = fa.map(f)
}
```

After importing the `FlatMap` instance (or defining it in the same file), the builder syntax no longer compiles.  I get the error:

```
error: value |@| is not a member of Option[Int]
[ERROR]   val test : Option[(Int, String)] = (Option(4) |@| Option("name")).map((_, _))
[ERROR]                                                 ^
```

Why does importing the `FlatMap` instance break the builder syntax?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is helpful to debug this using the `-Xlog-implicits` compiler flag, which will tell you which implicits the compiler tried, and why they failed. In your case, the very first message (at least for me) explains it:

```
scala> (Option(4) |@| Option("name")).map((_, _))
<console>:20: applySyntax is not a valid implicit value for Option[Int] => ?{def |@|: ?} because:
ambiguous implicit values:
 both value optionApplicative of type => cats.Applicative[Option]
 and value optionFlatmap of type => cats.FlatMap[Option]
 match expected type cats.Apply[Option]
       (Option(4) |@| Option("name")).map((_, _))
```

For the apply operations to work, an implicit `Apply[Option]` is needed, but both `Applicative` and `FlatMap` extend `Apply`, so the compiler does not know which one to choose. The simple solution to this is to combine both instances into an instance of `Monad`, which extends both `Applicative` and `FlatMap`.

```
import cats._
import cats.data.Kleisli
import cats.syntax.all._

implicit val optionMonad = new Monad[Option] {

  def pure[A](x: A): Option[A] = Option(x)

  def flatMap[A, B](fa: Option[A])(f: (A) => Option[B]): Option[B] = fa.flatMap(f)

}
```

Now everything works:

```
scala> val test : Option[(Int, String)] = (Option(4) |@| Option("name")).map((_, _))
test: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((4,name))

scala> val test2 : List[Int] => Option[Int] = {
  val f = (xs : List[Int]) => xs.headOption
  val g = (x : Int) => Option(x)
  Kleisli(f).andThen(g).run
}

test2: List[Int] => Option[Int] = <function1>
```